# Postgres: Error stopping service while uninstalling postgres

Tags: postgresql

I get this error while uninstalling postgres. I have been unable to connect to local database.

[image]

1. How can i check whether local postgres service is running in Windows 10 ?
2. How can i stop/start the service in Windows 10 ?

Answer (score 0):

To check if postgres is running win+r > services.msc > look for postgres service and see if it is running in the status column.

To stop the service you can either click on the postgres service you just found and click "Stop" in the top left.  If this fails to stop, try the below command in elevated CMD.

open CMD as administrator > type this: taskkill /F /IM pg_ctl.exe